# Link to specific part of webpage but at a certain height from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my page i have a static header that moves along with the user's scrolling. This works great but when i link to a specific div on the page using the standard method, the div ends up behind the header.

Basically i want to use

```
<a href="#css-tutorials">Cascading Style Sheet Tutorials</a>
<div name="css-tutorials">CSS Tutorials</div>
```

But how do i get it so that it doesn't put the div at the very top of the browser window? I checked one method that said add padding to the top of the div but that is not possible with my set up.

Here is the live [site](http://www.queensu.ca/drama/about-us-template.html). I need to go to the `id='Forms'` div when you click on the Forms link in the blue bar in the middle of the big picture.

Comment: You could move the anchor up further so that when the user lands there, the target location (#forms) is still lower than the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code which animates to that area when you click on `Forms & FAQs`

```
$('[href="#Forms"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#Forms').offset().top - $('#siteHeader').height() + 1})
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried this but nothing changed. I pasted the above code right into my JS file but when i click on the `Forms & FAQs` section it just jumps right to the area and it is still hidden

Comment: i have tried this in that site and its working.. if you are pasting this in js file you have to refresh the cache.. run it in console and see

Comment: I tried it in the console and it worked perfectly however it does not work from the JS file. I've refreshed my cache and removed all cache from my browsers and it still does not work. Funny thing is the same thing has been happening on a different page on the same site with some newly added code as well. I checked around and I cannot seem to find a solution

Comment: I fixed t by adding a script with the code in it right after the element